# I'd like to contact the company where I decline their offer

Tags: job-offer, united-states

2 months ago I got 2 offers from companies A and B. I decided to go for company "A" since they offered more salary.

I've worked there for 2 months and I don't like this company already.
I keep thinking about the company "B" where I declined their offer, 
and found out they are still looking for the position. The posting said "urgently".

Should I contact to them? Is it acceptable? I am not American and don't know the culture well, so I need your advice.

Comment: How can you be sure to will like them any more? They may end up being worse. Why were you so wrong about A?

Comment: Because of the team structure- the company B has the structure what I used to work for, and company A has a different structure, ( the company where I am working now), I am struggling to work here, I regret that I made a decision only for the money.

Comment: What culture aspect are you unsure about? How to phrase the e-mail or whether to phone them?

Comment: that's a good question-  I will be just honest , to say that I regret of my decision.

Comment: You need to think carefully about the team structure issue. Is there something inherently unreasonable about A's structure? If not, if it is just a matter of being unfamiliar, it may be better to stay with A. The problem is that you will see many different team structures in the course of your career, and need to be able to work with whatever your employer chooses.

Answer (score 6):

There is no harm in contacting the company where you declined the offer. There is nothing **unacceptable** about it. How they respond may depend on the availability of the position, how did they take your rejection and who are the concerned people now (Sometimes people change fast!)

Send them a note and politely ask if the position is still available you would like yourself to be reconsidered and see if and how they respond.

If they are still interested and get back to you, most likely you will have to explain why did you not chose them in the first place. You will have to be very careful on how to answer this. It should not sound like this company is your back-up option. You may want to do some research on the company and say why you want to join them now. Also, be prepared to accept the mistake you made previously and tell them that.

In any case, be absolutely sure you want to leave **A** and join **B** before you do any of this. If you approach **B** second time, keep it clear that you accept it if they offer you again. If you do not, then you permanently damage your relations with **B** and there will not be a third chance.

Answer (score -2):

> Should I contact them?

Only you can answer that question.

> Is it acceptable?

Well, you're going to burn bridges with Company A fairly badly. Don't expect anyone there, or anyone you dealt with there, to view you favourably in the future.

You're also going to have to answer some difficult questions from Company B: "why did you turn is down to months ago?" "if the money wasn't enough then, how do we know you're not going to leave us in two months when a different better paying job turns up?" etc.